# ¿Como recorrer una variable con un loop interno sin que el externo lo afecte en PHP?

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario que recorre valores de cinco machines (maquinas) a través de un `foreach` que toma todas los valores que estén enviados, seguido revisa que terminación tiene el name del campo de texto y lo asigna a la variable correspondiente según una comparación de patrones:

Para guardar correctamente el valor y no tener algo como nombre_1, color_1, etc, antes del llenado elimino lo que esta del guion bajo hacia el final.

**Esta es la función:**

```
function registerMachines(){
    foreach($_POST as $item => $value){
        if(preg_match('/_1$/', $item)){
            // Le saco los guiones 
            $item = explode("_", $item);
            // Uso solo la parte que tenga el item
            $item = $item[0];
            $data_1[$item] = $value;
        } elseif(preg_match('/_2$/', $item)){
            $item = explode("_", $item);
            $item = $item[0];
            $data_2[$item] = $value;
        } elseif(preg_match('/_3$/', $item)){
            $item = explode("_", $item);
            $item = $item[0];
            $data_3[$item] = $value;
        } elseif(preg_match('/_4$/', $item)){
            $item = explode("_", $item);
            $item = $item[0];
            $data_4[$item] = $value;
        } elseif(preg_match('/_5$/', $item)){
            $item = explode("_", $item);
            $item = $item[0];
            $data_5[$item] = $value;
        } else {
            $configData[$item] = $value;
        }
    }
}
```

**¿Que deseaba?**

Poder optimizar el llenado de los arreglos de manera que se creen variables por machine que poseo, evitando asi crear cada array (data_1, data2, etc). Ya realice el codigo aqui su explicaciòn.

```
$machines = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    foreach($_POST as $item => $value){
        echo "+++".$item."<br>";
        foreach($machines as $machine) {
            $match = '/_'.$machine.'$/';
            if(preg_match($match, $item)){
                $item = explode("_", $item);
                $item = $item[0];
                ${"machineData_".$machine}[$item] = $value;
            } else {
                echo $item."<br>";
                $configData[$item] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
```

**¿Como funciona?**

1--- Recorro todos los valores del $_POST.

2--- Recorro internamente cada machine ($machine).

3--- Creo el patron para comprobar basándome en el valor del loop.

4--- Si coincide elimino el la terminacion del $item (_1, _2, _3, etc).

5--- Creo la variable (array) con la sintaxis ${var.$machine} y le asigno el valor.

**¿Cual es el problema?:**

Cuando recorro el array del POST en la condicion ELSE se guardan todas las variables de forma repetida, es decir, se guardan con el _ ya removido por el explode, lo que hace que el array configdata se llene con los datos obtenidos de las machines.

**¿Que deseo?**

Quisiera poder recorrer cada valor POST y que solo se guardaran en el config data los valores que no tengan _ guion bajo, los cuales son solo 4.

Trate de colocarlos en un array =

```
$data = ["name", "space", "weight", "lift"];
```

**Datos para prueba (obtenidos del POST)**

```
["name"]=> string(5) "WWWWW"  ["space"]=> string(4)  ["weight"]=> int(2) 66  ["lift"]=> string(5) "WQWWW" ["RH1_1"]=> string(1) "3" ["RH2_1"]=> string(1) "3" ["RV1_1"]=> string(1) "3" ["RFO_1"]=> string(1) "3" ["CBO_1"]=> string(1) "3" ["OVA_1"]=> string(1) "3" ["INC_1"]=> string(1) "3" ["LBT_1"]=> string(1) "3" ["BNC_1"]=> string(1) "3" ["ACAB_1"]=> string(1) "3" ["AST_1"]=> string(1) "3" ["BSA_1"]=> string(1) "3" ["MRN_1"]=> string(1) "3"
```

Comment: ¿Puedes indicar un conjunto de datos para pruebas? ¿lo que se supone que contendría $_POST y lo que esperas obtener?

Comment: @Orici dejame publicarlo

Comment: @Orici el problema esta dando en el else, que esta almacenando valores que segun cumplen las condiciones del IF, donde solo quiero que se guarden unos 4 campos que son por defecto

Comment: Los datos para prueba que has puesto están incorrectos, esta por ejemplo: ["space"]=> string(4)  sin un valor, luego no se si hay algún anidamiento o algo.

Si puedes poner un formato: [
    ["name"]   =>"WWWWW",
    ["space"]  => "xxxx",
    ["weight"] => 66,
    ["lift"]   => "WQWWW",
    ["RH1_1"]  => "3",
    ["RH2_1"]  => "3", ], ya genial

Comment: @Orici trate de copiarlos a mano por celular jejeje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**El codigo final fue este:**

```
        $ConfigData = array();
        $machines=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
        $mainData = ["name", "space", "weight", "lift"];
            foreach($_POST as $item => $value){
                if (in_array($item, $mainData)) {
                    $ConfigData[$item] = $value;
                } else {
                    foreach($machines as $machine) {
                        $match = '/_'.$machine.'$/';
                        if(preg_match($match, $item)){
                            $item = explode("_", $item);
                            $item = $item[0];
                            ${"MachineData_".$machine}[$item] = $value;
                        } 
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar lo siguiente:

```
<?php
class OptimizeMachines {

    private static $counter = 1;

    public static function register($number_of_machines=5) {
        //self::$n_machines = $number_of_machines;

        foreach($_POST as $item => $value) {

            // Le saco los guiones
            $item = explode("_", $item);

            // Uso solo la parte que tenga el item
            $item = $item[0];
            ${"data_".self::$counter}[$item] = $value;

            self::$counter++;

            //reinicializa contador
            if (self::$counter > $number_of_machines) {
                self::$counter = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

} //class
```

Es una primera idea, te permite variar el número de máquinas. Si añades un set de datos para pruebas, iría más a lo seguro.

Comment: entiendo tu idea, hacer un contador mas no un ciclo, dejame revisar

Comment: hay un problema, cada vez que toma un valor se pasa al siguiente, ocurriendo esto nombre_1 , color_2, peso_3, deberia ser primero todo con 1, luego con 2, luego con 3, no un indice distinto para cada valor del POST